# Args are being sliced after first word | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

[image]

```
exports.exec = async (client, message, args, level, settings, texts) => {

    const user = args[0];
    const text = args[1]

    // Fires Error message that the command wasn't ran correctly.
    if (!user) {
        return client.emit('commandUsage', message, this.help);
    }
    // Fires Error message that the command wasn't ran correctly.

    try {
        const { body } = await snekfetch.get(`https://nekobot.xyz/api/imagegen?type=${user.toLowerCase() === "realdonaldtrump" ? "trumptweet" : "tweet"}&username=${user.startsWith("@") ? user.slice(1) : user}&text=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`);
        message.channel.send("", { file: body.message });

/* * * * */
```

As you can see in the gif, anything past the first word (`it`) in this case is sliced. I'm lost to as why, am I'm unsure if it's due to `const text = args[1]` or not.

I don't think `const text = args.join (" ")` would work at all, nor have I tried but fairly positive it wouldn't.

Apologies for the noobiness, I'm new to discord.js :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely due to `args[1]`, assuming `args` is an array of words used in the message, split by space, the `1` position will always contain only the second word.

What you want is something like this:

```
const [user, ...restArgs] = args;
const text = restArgs.join(' ');
```

This will take the first element as the `user`, and use the rest of the array for the text, not just the second element.

Comment: Many thanks, I knew it was due to the args damnit. But didn't know RestArgs and such was a thing, that's cool. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Imaginebeingme You could achieve the same effect with `const text = args.slice(1).join(' ')`, without the "fanciness" :)